# How to customize the receipt for cash jounral (fcbj) in sap (abap)?

Tags: abap, finance, sap-erp

I want to use different templates of receipt for different company codes in cash journal. Can this be done without coding? How to do this in ABAP?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to solve the problem.

1. Use SHD0 to create a variant transaction.
   https://community.sap.com/t5/enterprise-resource-planning-blogs-by-members/how-to-create-a-transaction-variant/ba-p/13205260
   This allows to set the first part of a transation as a screen variant.
   Getting to know transaction variants and the tool is the main hurdle.
2. For an ABAP coder the easier way be to create a simple ABAP using

CALL TRANSACTION 'FBCJ' using bdc_tab mode 'A'   " or mode 'E'.

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapcall_transaction_using.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@

USing a BDC Table you prefill the screen/s as much as you like.
CAll in mode E or A and see the difference and work out what suits best.